# Radio button not showing in chrome

Tags: php, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, google-chrome

I created custom  radio button in signup form but they are not showing in chrome.

Pls check the code and help. below is the link to the form

http://landandpropertymarket.com/signup.php

```
<div class="form-group">

<label><input type="radio" name="usertype" value="1" >Agent  &nbsp; &nbsp;</label>
<label><input type="radio" name="usertype" value="2" >Owner &nbsp; &nbsp; </label>
 <label><input type="radio" name="usertype" value="3">User</label>
  </div>
```

Comment: or maybe you look at a cached version of the page?

Answer (score 0):

I saw this:

[image]

Check your chrome version

Comment: Google Chrome is up to date
Version 83.0.4103.106 (Official Build) (64-bit)

Comment: That is my chrome version. Not showing yet, i will try to confirm from a friend laptop. Thanks

Comment: I'm 83.0.4103.106 (Official buildl) (64 bits) too, try to clean your browser cache

Comment: Perfecto, valid the solution for other who will need it ;)